# Side effects of application level initialization of libraries?

Tags: android, android-context

I came across some libraries that needs to be in `Application` class.

Lets have a look at [PrefCompat](https://github.com/tushar-acharya/PrefCompat).

First we initialize it

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Pref.init(this);
    }
}
```

and then we can use it anywhere like

```
Pref.putString("name", "Tushar");
```

Which is convenient, looks nice and advantage of that is you don't have to pass context again and again inside activities and fragments like

```
Pref.with(this).putString("name", "Tushar");
```

it makes the code look beautiful too (in my opinion).

So my question basically is:

> Is there any side effects of initializing the library or any class
>   like that?

any thoughts with some explanation will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Everything I listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062979/is-using-the-application-class-as-a-hack-workaround-for-configuration-changes-ac/40063079#40063079) would be a concern. Plus, `onCreate()` of your `Application` is called on the main application thread, so whatever libraries you initialize there need to be cheap.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, that explains well, one quick question though is there any problem in above case if we use it in background thread?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not certain what "if we use it in background thread" means in this context.

Comment: am sorry I meant to ask after initialization in application (Main thread) if we try to use something like `Pref.putString("name", "Tushar")` in some background thread? you don't have to answer if my question sounds silly :)

Comment: Well, you don't really have an opportunity to fork a background thread before `onCreate()` of your `Application` completes, so there is no problem there. You would have to ask the authors of the library what the threading rules are for using the library.